# Obtaining accuracy of device orientation from Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Tags: android, orientation, device, imu

I am currently working on an compass activity on Android. To provide the orientation of the smartphone, I use the ***Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR*** sensor and I would like to determine the accuracy of the obtained values.

According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#sensor), the method gives the following values:

- values[0]: x*sin(θ/2)
- values[1]: y*sin(θ/2)
- values[2]: z*sin(θ/2)
- values[3]: cos(θ/2)
- values[4]: estimated heading Accuracy (in radians) (-1 if unavailable)

What interest me most is the so-called *heading Accuracy* value. Unfortunately, after multiple tests, it appears that this value is always 0, and I can't understand why.

If anyone I help me to understand the whole problem, I would be very grateful. Thanks.